# Winforms draw lines over text box

Tags: c#, winforms, wndproc

I have a display that customizes text and as the user customizes it, I want the text to display. One of the customizations available is an "x-out" which should draw a large "X" over all 5 characters of the text. So when the checkbox "X-Out" is checked, it should update the text from this:

[image]

To this:

[image]

The box itself is a RichTextBox contained within a Panel. I have tried using the Paint event in the panel, but it draws it underneath the RichTextBox (that's the little red lines on the corners). I have also tried using a custom RichTextBox control like [at this website](https://web.archive.org/web/20131130031200/http://www.codedblog.com/2007/09/17/owner-drawing-a-windowsforms-textbox/). This code does work, but only if I do not set text and color in the RichTextBox. If I set text and color and then check the checkbox, the WndProc method is not called.  How do I trigger the WndProc method with Message.msg 15? Here is the code:

**Form**

```
public partial class ButtonDataForm : Form
{
  CustomRichTextBox button1;

  public ButtonDataForm()
  {
    InitializeComponent()
  }

  void OnFormLoad(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
    cstmRichTextBox = new CustomRichTextBox(richTextBox1);
  }

  void OnXOutChecked()
  {
    cstmRichTextBox.IsChecked = xoutCheckbox.Checked;
    cstmRichTextBox.ParentTex.Refresh(); // This does not trigger the WndProc message on cstmRichTextBox
  }
}
```

**CustomRichTextBox**

```
public class CustomRichTextBox : NativeWindow
{
  public RichTextBox ParentTextBox { get; private set; }
  Graphics textBoxGraphics;
  public bool IsChecked { get; set; }

  public CustomRichTextBox(RichTextBox tb)
  {
    ParentTextBox = tb;
    textBoxGraphics = Graphics.FromHwnd(tb.Handle);
    AssignHandle(ParentTextBox.Handle);
  }

  protected override void WndProc(ref Message m}
  {
    switch(m.Msg)
    {
      case 15:
        parentTextBox.Invalidate();
        base.WndProc(ref m);
        DrawXOut();
        break;
      default:
        base.WndProc(ref m);
        break;
    }
  }

  void DrawXOut()
  {
    if (IsChecked)
    {
      Pen xpen = new Pen(ParentTextBox.ForeColor, 3);
      Point topLeft = ParentTextBox.Location;
      int x1 = topLeft.X + ParentTextBox.Width;
      int y1 = topLeft.Y + ParentTextBox.Height;
      Point topRight = new Point(x1, topLeft.Y);
      Point bottomLeft = new Point(topLeft.X, y1);
      Point bottomRight = new Point(x1, y1);
      textBoxGraphics.DrawLine(xpen, topLeft, bottomRight);
      textBoxGraphics.DrawLine(xpen, bottomLeft, topRight); 
    }
  }
}
```

**EDIT:**

I tried placing a transparent panel on the bottom panel and drawing inside it when the Paint event fired. The event fires, but *nothing* showed up in the panel. Am I calculating the location incorrectly?

```
void OnXOutChecked()
{
  panel1.Refresh();
}

void OnPanel1Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
    Pen xpen = new Pen(Color.Red, 3);
    Point topLeft = panel1.Location;
    int x1 = topLeft.X + panel1.Width;
    int y1 = topLeft.Y + panel1.Height;
    Point topRight = new Point(x1, topLeft.Y);
    Point bottomLeft = new Point(topLeft.X, y1);
    Point bottomRight = new Point(x1, y1);
    e.Graphics.DrawLine(xpen, topLeft, bottomRight);
    e.Graphics.DrawLine(xpen, bottomLeft, topRight);
}
```

[image]

Comment: If you just use the RichTextBox to show something and don't intend to use it to edit something then i would say simply don't use ist. Just a simple control as surface and paint everything including the text yourself. I assume its way easier then getting this combination working.

Comment: You're right, I do not need to edit anything. What type of control do you suggest?

Comment: The panel you seem to have already or used in your last edit? Just paint everything in its OnPaint event not just the optional X-Out.

Comment: How do you paint text?

Comment: You already show using DrawLine on the Graphics object in the last code. You find almost everything you need on that Graphics object. For Text there are a few DrawString overloads. [Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/api/system.drawing.graphics.drawstring?view=dotnet-plat-ext-7.0) with some examples.

Comment: @Ralf DrawString is for printing to a printer.  User should use [TextRenderer.DrawText](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.textrenderer.drawtext?view=windowsdesktop-7.0) instead.

Comment: @LarsTech No. Both can be used against "Devices". Diff is that one is GDI based while the other is GDI+ based. Both work will slight different results.

Comment: Thank you, @Ralf, I have something usable now.

Answer (score 2):

I just modified your `CustomRichTextBox` a bit:

```cs
public class CustomRichTextBox : RichTextBox
{
    private bool xOut;

    public bool XOut
    {
        get => xOut;
        set
        {
            xOut = value;
            Invalidate();
        }
    }

    protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
    {
        switch (m.Msg)
        {
            case 15:
                base.WndProc(ref m);
                if (xOut)
                    DrawXOut();
                break;
            default:
                base.WndProc(ref m);
                break;
        }
    }

    private void DrawXOut()
    {
        using var g = Graphics.FromHwnd(Handle);
        g.DrawLine(Pens.Red, 0, 0, Width, Height);
        g.DrawLine(Pens.Red, 0, Height, Width, 0);
    }

    protected override void OnHScroll(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnHScroll(e);
        Invalidate();
    }

    protected override void OnVScroll(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnVScroll(e);
        Invalidate();
    }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is a very unreliable approach, drawing on top of the control and expecting it to work in all possible scenarios (and there can be many!).

You can just place a transparent picture box on top of the text box with a transparent bitmap that has two crossed red lines.

Comment: The lines have to be the same color as the text, which can change as you can see from the user controls.

Comment: And no problem to generate the bitmap at runtime, based on the settings.

Comment: I doubt the transparent thingy works. Winforms has no transparency in its actual sense. Setting transparent color means typically "paint the background color of my parent control here".

Comment: @Ralf, this is absolutely not true when it comes to GDI / Win32.

Comment: @Nick Maybe but that has only slightly todo with what Winforms does.

Comment: And if you read my advice carefully, what WinForm does has little to do with what I recommend. :-)

Answer (score 0):

To be honest, I don't think this is something you want to be doing. You are abusing the richtextbox for something it wasn't intended to. I don't know your true intentions, but maybe a strike-through might be a valid solution?

My experiences tell me it's better to use the components as-is and don't change them too much.

### An actual answer

If you really want to, you could do something like this: (Based on Nicks answer.)

```
    public class MyTextbox : RichTextBox
    {
        PictureBox pictureBox = new PictureBox();
        public MyTextbox()
        {
            this.Controls.Add(pictureBox);
            pictureBox.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
            pictureBox.BackColor = Color.Transparent;
            pictureBox.Paint += PictureBox_Paint;
            pictureBox.BringToFront();
        }

        private void PictureBox_Paint(object? sender, PaintEventArgs e)
        {
            var pen = new Pen(this.ForeColor);
            e.Graphics.DrawLine(pen, 0, 0, this.Width, this.Height);
            e.Graphics.DrawLine(pen, 0, this.Height, this.Width, 0);
        }
    }
```

Comment: How is the PictureBox.Paint triggered?  Is it enough to refresh MyTextbox?

Comment: I'm not sure, you should try this. Otherwise override the Refresh from the textbox and use that to refresh the base and the picturebox.

Comment: This does work, however, as @Ralf said above, the transparency doesn't work.  So the pictureBox is painted the same color as MyTextbox, which obscures the actual Text in MyTextbox.  Is there no way to add text and lines to the same control?

Comment: AFAIK, its not possible to do this on the control directly without the WndProc override.